# Web scraping using fetch - promise doesn't resolve

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, promise, fetch

I am trying to fetch a particular website, and I already mimic all the request headers that Chrome sends and I am still getting a pending promise that never resolves.

Here is my current code and headers:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');


(async () => {

    console.log('Starting fetch');
    const fetchResponse = await fetch('https://www.g2a.com/rocket-league-pc-steam-key-global-i10000003107015', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {            
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'           
            
        }
    })
    
    console.log('I never see this console.log: ', fetchResponse);


    if(fetchResponse.ok){
        console.log('ok');
    }else {        
        console.log('not ok');
    }

    console.log('Leaving...');
})();
```

This is the console logs I can read:

```
Starting fetch
This is a pending promise:  Promise { <pending> }
not ok
Leaving...
```

Is there something I can do here? I notice on similar questions that for this specific website, I only need to use Accept-Language header, I already tried that, but still the promise never gets resolved.

Also read on another question that they have security against Node.js requests, maybe I need to use another language?

Comment: Hey @jonrsharpe thanks for ur reply , it doesnt seem a problem in my code I believe I am doing things right, did you found something bad in the code above? The promise never resolves, it never enters on the 'then' block.

Comment: The program doesnt end , it halts execution after the last console.log because there is a promise in the background waiting.

Comment: If I use await it stops after the first console.log and never proceeds, already tried that as well.

Comment: Yes I left that code there, because I was doing await before the change to the 'then' solution, it's doing nothing right now the way it is on my question at the moment, you are right yes.

Comment: Just did it now, you can copy and execute it, you will see 'Starting fetch' and nothing else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a better time using async functions and await instead of then here.

I'm assuming your Node.js doesn't support top-level await, hence the last .then.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const headers = {
  "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36",
  "Accept-Language": "en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
  "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
};

async function doFetch(url) {
  console.log("Starting fetch");
  const fetchResponse = await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers,
  });
  console.log(fetchResponse);
  if (!fetchResponse.ok) {
    throw new Error("Response not OK");
  }
  const data = await fetchResponse.json();
  return data;
}

doFetch("https://www.g2a.com/rocket-league-pc-steam-key-global-i10000003107015").then((data) => {
  console.log("All done", data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @AKX but that didn't work as well, I see in the logs 'Starting fetch' but then it doesn't proceed, promise never resolves.